Identify a sci fi movie or TV show about aliens, ships government conspiracy

It may have something to do with the Roswell incident and area 51.
The US military personnel tried to hack the ship, causing twins with super spiritual powers to die.
In the plot, some Hollywood celebrities involved maybe themselves are aliens , I don't remember, there's  something about the dude's phone.
The aliens disguised as human beings, but did show their form as the typical little gray man later.
The aliens were indeed survivors of Roswell crash.
The ship was recovered and operational.
Not an old movie or show, as most 10 years, I think. 


causing twins with super spiritual powers died What does that mean?

It sounds like you could be describing Taken. A 2002 miniseries by Steven Spielberg. There is a scene where the military try to use a set of psychic female twins to operate an alien space ship but their psychic powers are not nearly strong enough and both die.
The aliens crash in Roswell as part of a scouting mission and the lone survivor "John" makes himself look human through projection although the aliens are actually the classic small gray men.




I've not watched the show, but this sounds to me like Roswell. The siblings are actually clones, they were int he Roswell crash, and they do have some limited superpowers.
It is a little earlier than your target, though (1999 through 2002).
